# How to bind array with ng-bind-html directive in angularJS?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I want to show for every item different description. 
This is the controller:

```
todoApp.controller('todos',function($scope,todoFactory){
      todoFactory.getTodos().success(function (data) {
        courses = x2js.xml_str2json(data);
        $scope.todos = courses.rss.channel.item;
        for(var i = 0 ; i < $scope.todos.length ; i++){
          item = $scope.todos[i];
         console.log(item.description);
          $scope.message = item.description;
        }
      });
```

this is the html:

```
<div ng-controller="todos" class="list" style="padding-top: 8%">
      <div class="list card" ng-repeat="todo in todos | filter:search" >
        <div class="item item-avatar" ng-click="openLink(todo.link)" >
          <img src="Bla-Bla-Logo-1.png">
          <h2>{{todo.title}}</h2>
          <p>{{todo.pubDate | limitTo:25 }}</p>
        </div>

        <div class="item item-body">
          <p ng-bind-html="message"></p>
          <p>
            <a href="#" class="subdued">1 Like</a>
            <a href="#" class="subdued">5 Comments</a>
          </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--end list card-->
    </div>
    <!--end todos-->
```

Just to explain the code I get xml and convert into json so todos is array of objects.
Message is entering every object and get the description (but in the description has tags so i use ng-bind-html directive to show it properly).

I understand that $scope.message will hold just the last description. How to make it to belong in the ng-repeat so I can get different description for different item?

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you storing description in $scope.message? Just use todo.description inside your ng-repeat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace

```
<p ng-bind-html="message"></p>
```

with

```
 <p ng-bind-html="todo.description"></p>
```

Comment: No need for FOR now.

Answer (score 1):

please provide the data which is you want to displayed repeatedly.
How data is represented.You are getting last one because it is overriding.

The "ngBind" attribute tells Angular to replace the text content of the specified HTML element with the value of a given expression, and to update the text content when the value of that expression changes.

Typically, you don't use "ngBind" directly, but instead you use the double curly markup like {{ expression }} which is similar but less verbose.

Comment: It should be comment.

Comment: Please, everybody is learning mention not. Just try both way.